# How to make a custom configuration in Struts 2?

Tags: xml, configuration, struts2

I like to create an XML or a property file for my key and value pairs.

For example, I like to save a url in an XML or a property file and then get the value of it in my classes.

I know that I can create an XML file and then use an XML parser to do it, but is there a standard way of doing it in Struts 2?

I'm pretty new to Struts 2..so feel free to suggest anything!

Thank you in advances!

Comment: You can also @Inject properties set in an S2 config file and avoid having to load them up yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, I don't think there is anything special  required in struts2 for this, you can use standard java.util.Properties

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load( new FileInputStream("url.properties"));
...
props.get("someurl");
```

in your url.properties

```
someurl=http://someurlsite.com/some/url
```

Comment: // exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: /* Your comment is really a comment! */

Comment: @Steven Benitez // This is weird...I put (at) kunal //, but then...stackoverflow removed (at) kunal.